# Chart.js xAxis linear scale : strange behavior

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to use linear scale on x-axis in my chart.js chart.
I add some code beause stackoverflow makes it obligatory when adding a jsfiddle url, but I don't see the point :

```
var options={
    scales:{
    xAxes:[{ type: "linear"}]
  }
};
```

I'm getting a very strange chart (2nd one) : http://jsfiddle.net/t0krmau8/

In the first chart, I'd like to get more space between 2 and 4 (2 times more space than between 1 and 2), that's why I'm using a linear scale.

Am I using the linear scale wrong? Or should I use something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not providing the data in correct format for the `scatter line` plot.

The correct format to provide the data is described by the following example from Chart.js Docs.

```
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx/* your canvas context*/, {
 type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Scatter Dataset',
            data: [{
                x: -10,
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: 0,
                y: 10
            }, {
                x: 10,
                y: 5
            }]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

[source](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-scatter-line-charts)

I think the `x` and `y` should be separable into different arrays, but you can always do a combination step and combine them into objects.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't looking at the right place. I definitively hate Chart.js documentation

Comment: Thank you for this answer. it help me after spending hours trying to figure out where my graph was.

Comment: This just draws a vertical line for me... and the linked page shows completely different code, without {x,y} objects in data.

Comment: @riv This answer is based on version 2.4.0 of chart.js which is ancient(6-7 years old) and I couldn't find the documentation any more. The closest one is documentation of [2.6.0](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.6.0/charts/scatter.html#scatter-chart). If you want to have a look at the current version have a look at [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#scatter-chart)