# Chart.js line chart with correctly spaced x labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

By default, chart.js seems to space out its x labels equally instead of plotting the (x,y) pairs in space.

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
  labels: [0, 1, 10],
  datasets: [{
      data: [1, 2, 1]
    }]
  },
}
```

This puts the "1" label halfway between the 0 and the 10 on the x-axis ([here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj1kqoe4/5/)). How can I make it locate 1/10 of the way to 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Chart.js xAxis linear scale : strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281398/chart-js-xaxis-linear-scale-strange-behavior) you need a linear x-axis with data supplied as x,y pairs.

So, it needs to be:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Linear Dataset',
                    data: [{ x: 0, y: 1}
                          ,{x: 1, y: 2 }
                          ,{ x: 10, y: 1} ]
                          }]
                  },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'linear'
                        ,position: 'bottom'
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```